# Magento Checkout: Item out of stock charges customer but no order / order confirmation

Tags: magento, checkout, magento-1.6

I am using Magento 1.6 with the out-of-the-box one page checkout.
Upon the final submit, after the customer has reviewed their order, there seems to be a glitch: If an item has become out of stock, the customer is notified and the order seems not to be going through (no order is created and no confirmation page). However, authorize.net does get the complete transaction request and charges the customer. It seems to only happen if an item has become out of stock. (Customer could be lingering to hit the submit button for quite a while.)

What can I do? Add a java script function to check upon stock on clicking submit?
Is this a known bug?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Is your system set to allow Backorders?

System > Config > Catalog > Inventory > Backorders "No Backorders".

If that is set to disallow backorders I wonder why the add-to-cart button even displays.

If you are using a custom template I might start there in troubleshooting. Switch back to a default template and see if this issue persists.

Comment: We do not allow Backorders. and there is no add-to cart button if out of stock. However, what if after the final order review the customer lingers to click submit? And in that time frame, maybe a minute, someone else bought the last item?
We are also using magento's default one page checkout - nothing custom right now. Thanks